# No such file or directory: 'newcred.json'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I am having a really frustrating time trying to import a json file to my python script.

When I run the file individually it works fine. However I am trying to import the file into another area of my system

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/home/seamus/code/544-dss/controllers/google')
import google_worksheets

test = google_worksheets.g_sheets()
print(test.service)
```

When I do this it works until hitting this line of code in my class

```
ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('newcred.json', 
self.scope)
```

Then I get the error message:

No such file or directory: 'newcred.json'

The file newcred.json is in the same directory as google_worksheets and when I run google_worksheets on it's own it works fine (right click file and click run).

Any suggestion on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated as this is very annoying?

My folder structure is like this:
/home/seamus/code/544-dss/controllers/google

with **init**.py, google_worksheets.py and newcred.json all living inside the google folder.

Thanks very much

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We can't debug your code if we can only see 6 lines of it.

Answer (score 0):

Relative path are resolved againts the current working directory, not against the path of the python script or module trying to access the file. You have to use an absolute path. You can use the `__file__` magic variable and `os.path` function to build this absolute path from your module.